# Curl form/file upload in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, curl

I am a complete newbie in VB.NET but I am trying to implement the following curl command in VB.NET code:

```
curl -u <userName>:<password> -XPOST -F 'installer=@OnHoliday.wav' 'https://192.168.1.51?archiveSpace=1'
```

Can anybody point me in the right direction?  Should I use a httpwebrequest, webclient, httpclient?  I have been pounding my head against a wall for the last two days but I can't seem to get it to work.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Curl command to html or vb.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14835916/curl-command-to-html-or-vb-net)

Comment: I have been searching here and other places for two days now.  I saw that post but I can't the file to load.  This is a multipart form with the file.  I saw a good article using a webclient but that defaults to "file=@thefile"  where I need "installer=@thefile".  I could not find a way to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me know how this `.Net 4.5` console app works for you...

```
Imports System
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Http
Imports System.Net.Http.Headers
Imports System.Threading.Tasks

Module Module1

    Private Credentials As New NetworkCredential("userName", "password")
    Private Client As New HttpClient(New HttpClientHandler With {.PreAuthenticate = True, .Credentials = Credentials})

    Private Const FormFieldName As String = "installer"
    Private Const Filename As String = "OnHoliday.wav"
    Private Const ContentType As String = "audio/x-wav"
    Private Const Url As String = "https://192.168.1.51?archiveSpace=1"

    Sub Main()
        With DoPost()
            .Wait()
            Debug.Print(.Result)
        End With
    End Sub

    Async Function DoPost() As Task(Of String)
        Dim FileContent = New ByteArrayContent(File.ReadAllBytes(Filename))
        FileContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(ContentType)

        Dim RequestContent = New MultipartFormDataContent(Guid.NewGuid.ToString)
        RequestContent.Add(FileContent, FormFieldName, Filename)

        With Await Client.PostAsync(Url, RequestContent)
            Return Await .Content.ReadAsStringAsync
        End With
    End Function

End Module
```

References:

- [MultipartFormDataContent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.multipartformdatacontent(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [ByteArrayContent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.bytearraycontent(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [HttpClient.PostAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138245(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [HttpClientHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138157(v=vs.110).aspx)